# Vuforia AR Camera working from the second attempt on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, arcore

I have an `Android` application which I created using `Unity` and C`#`, it also uses `Vuforia`. I have an `AR Camera`, which shows a black screen when I have just installed the application and gave camera permission to it, but when I close the app and start it again, everything works fine. I did a lot of searches, so what I found and tried- to Switch automatic graphics to `OpenGls2`, to set minimization to none, etc. Upgrading `Vuforia` version will not work for me. Also `ARCamera` works for phones supporting `ARCore` and does not work for phones not having `ARCore`. So I guess, the issue is within the architecture of the phone. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It must be related to camera API. I don't know how Vuforia is trying to initialize the camera. Seems like it tries to initialize it before successful permission result on old Android versions. You can delay Vuforia initialization to be after the permission check. There is an option to set Vuforia delayed initialization, but it would be better to make a preload scene where you do check all permissions and maybe other setup and then load the scene where Vuforia is used.

Update: Please try to update xr plugins for Unity (they are packages now), update Unity itself to the latest version. Do not use unity beta. Se if there are some recommendations from Vuforia of which unity version is the latest supported. Youc also try to create a new unity project from scratch and then import the latest vuforia, then try camera on android, then if all good, import all the resources for your app.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have tried delayed initialization as well, no result. actually i have a preload scene asking permissions, but it again seems that Vuforia initializes the camera before all this.